# Cannot Subscribe or Publish with latest release & Arduino Diecimila

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed and compiled the latest version of the rosserial stack. I have been attempting to run the samples (Hello World, etc.), after I wasn't able to get my own code to work. It turns out, none of the sample work properly.

For example, the hello world sample, when I start the python client there are no errors, but the topic from the arduino is never published.

i.e. run:
roscore
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
rostopic list

The topic is not there.

I have verified that the arduino is running properly, and on the correct port (and no port errors are given). The only output is:
[INFO] [WallTime: 1331948389.955027] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1331948389.956859] Connected on /dev/ttyUSB0 at 57600 baud

Device is Diecimila, running on ros-electric/Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

No errors in making the packages, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29898/cannot-subscribe-or-publish-with-latest-release-&-arduino-diecimila/) by [srlake](https://answers.ros.org/users/1994/srlake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-03-16**:
Do you see the message "Lost sync with device, restarting..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you could try with another Arduino if you have one nearby. I completed these tutorials a few weeks ago using indigo-ubuntu 12.04 lts with a duemilanove just for configuration informations and to confirm that it is supposed to work.

Best regards,

Pascal

---

Originally posted by [pascal.fortin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20693/pascal.fortin/) with karma: 16 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0